# SQL select query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me how to get the value from `SELECT` query from a table

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string select_qry = "SELECT ID, USER, FILE, DATE, LASTUSED from FILE_INFO where USER = '" + user + "'"; // ID is primary key
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select_qry);
   GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
   GridView1.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.Connection = conn1;
   conn1.Open();
   sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
   sda.Fill(dt);
   return dt;
}
```

I have different USERS I want to get ID of user if user is different say 'Sheena' has ID value from 1-10 but if user is 'Sara' and she is having ID from 11-20 so I want to get specially ID of particular user how do I get ID from select query can any one know then please help me out :)

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create your queries. Use parameterised queries! (Google "SQL injection")

Answer (score 3):

if the ID will always be first in the select statement you can call this:

VB.NET

```
var dt = GetData(cmd);
dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("ID")
```

C#.NET

```
var dt = GetData(cmd);
dt.Rows[0]["ID"];
```

Comment: hii mark will this will give me `dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0) ` me the ID of first row of any USER ?

Comment: For VB the first item is the row, the second Item is column so for user 1 you call dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0)  for user 2 call dt.Rows.Item(1).Item(0)


For C# call dt.Rows[0][0] for user 1 for user 2 call dt.Rows[1][0]

Comment: but dont know the user value suppose if user is on 8th or 9th position i dont know the no. of user then how could i handle this ?

Comment: if your looking to loop through you can loop through using foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)  or for(int i=0; i< dt.Rows.Count; i++)

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting you quite well. but

Sample data

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("userName", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "Sheena");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Meena");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Teena");
```

To get id of first row.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // return id in first row.
    int id = (int)dt.Rows[0]["id"];
}
```

DataTable Select method

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("userName = 'Meena'");

    if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
            int id2 = (int)dr[0]["id"];
    }

}
```

There are other methods too but these are quickly I can write.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that in your query like

```
Select case id >= 11 and id <= 20 then 'specially id' end as ID ......
```

Because 'user' is a parameter so you can know the id range when you creating the query.

So that , there is no need any logic in your source code , just fetch data as @Mark said..